# UITableView has loaded data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a subview where there is an uitableview that gets data from an online server (title, subtitle and image). When I click the button that shows the subview it takes a little time to get there using WiFi connection, but under 3G network it takes longer, so that you really feel the gap between loading the view and having pressed the button

what I'd like to do, is to display an uiactivityindicatorview when you press the button and after loading the view, and when it has loaded stop the activity indicator

how can I check that the uitableview has finished loading ?
do you have other suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchronious requests or threading (take a look at NSOperation)

Comment: could you please give me more informations or a small sample ? thanks

Comment: There is NSOperationQueue in which u can add NSOperations.
Each NSOperation is a URL connection hit in a separate thread.This will not block the UI and multithreading is achieved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look into doing network operations asynchronously, rather than blocking the main UI's thread. ASIHTTPRequest is a really good library for this: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, if you are not using an asynchronous approach to this, I strongly suggest you to do so, because otherwise you will block your application for as long as the data is being downloaded.

With that said, you could show the activity indicator while the data is being loaded, and that is until the delegate method

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

is called. Then, your table should be populated with the data and the indicator would dissapear.

I hope this helped you a bit

Comment: I don't use your method in my app, but it gives me a hint about performing some tasks while the table is loading data. Thank you.